# Configure IIS authentication from another domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, intranet

I have the following scenario:
I have Web Application hosted on IIS and I am in domain `a.b.com`. The IIS is configured to authenticate the users with windows authentication and everyone that in the domain `a.b.com` can enter the site.
But there are users that in another domain lets call it `c.d.com` and they can't enter the site with their windows credentials because the IIS check against `a.b.com`...

How can I configure IIS to check for windows user in `c.d.com`?

Comment: Are there any domain trusts between those two domains?

Comment: How can I know such detail? I really don't understand in domain trusts...  there is a way to check it?

Comment: When you say you're in domain `a.b.com`, is that a Windows domain (Active Directory) in which you have a user account? And `c.d.com`, are they affiliated with `a.b.com`?

Comment: Both are Active Directory and I have user account in both, I don't know what is mean "affiliated with a.b.com"...

Answer (score 7):

Try below process.

1. Go to (IIS) Manager.
2. Right Click on Web-Application.
3. Select **Edit Permission** option.
4. Select **Security** tab.
5. Click on **Edit...** button.
6. Click on **Add...** button.
7. **Write your new user domain name**
8. Click **OK**
9. select newly added User name from **Group or user names:**
10. tick on **Allow**
11. Click **OK**

-It should work

Comment: It success partially if I am in the computer where the IIS it is success but from other computer it is not success...

Comment: "Write your new user domain name" means, I'll have to add all users of the Domain on the server ?

Answer (score -6):

You need to set the identity of the application pool of that website:

1. Open IIS
2. Under "Application Pools" right click on your website's pool, choose "Advanced Settings..."
3. Edit "Identity" field
4. set "Custom account" credentials
5. Recycle just in case

You application is now using the user you've configured.

Comment: I don't understand your answer I want to add 100 users from domain c.d.com how can I do it?